# What is the C# equivalent to Delphi's FormatFloat?

Tags: c#, delphi, formatting

I'm porting some Delphi code to C#. I can't find a similar function to Delphi's `FormatFloat`.

I've got this line of code in Delphi

```
str := FormatFloat('000', 1);
```

which assigns to `str` the string `'001'`. Note the leading zeros.

How can I achieve the same result in C#?

Comment: See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx) for specific formatting for left-padding with zeros.

Comment: Nope, because the digits need to add before it. It's confusing, but in delphi it's called FormatFloat, but i use it for integers (A)

But the answer of @akton was right and did the trick :P

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks, bookmarked it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) with [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). For example:

```
int a = 1;
string.Format("{0:000}", a); // returns "001"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ToString() method :

```
int number = 3;
string fmt = number.ToString("D3");
```

string variable fmt will have value "003"